# Javascript Regex to comma separated last 3digitand then 2 digit

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for a regex to separate amount in american comma format like below

```
1111111111 to 1,11,11,11,111
```

I tried like below

```
function formatNumber(num) {
  return num.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{2})*(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1,')
}

console.info(formatNumber(2665.68)) 
console.info(formatNumber(102665.68)) 
console.info(formatNumber(111102665.32)) 
console.info(formatNumber(11111111.32))
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tyLh82og/

basically last three digit then 2 digit to the start.

I have found many regex which are separating 3 digits or 2 digits or 4 digits.

I tried combining 3 and digit separation, but lack of regex knowledge could not get.

Please help

Thanks

Comment: I have basic idea of regex, but unable to get how to make group of end with last 3 then 2 to the start, could you please give me any hint

Comment: I have updated the post

Comment: Ok, I see, try `.replace(/(?!^)(?=(?:\d{2})*\d{3}(?:\.|$))/g, ',')`. If the fractional part is always present you may remove the `(?:\.|$)` alternation  and replace it with `\.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
.replace(/(?!^)(?=(?:\d{2})*\d{3}(?:\.|$))/g, ',')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cxOFFD/1)

**Details**

- `(?!^)` - not the start of the string position
- `(?=(?:\d{2})*\d{3}(?:\.|$))` - immediately to the right of the current position, there must be

  - `(?:\d{2})*`  -zero or more occurrences of two digits
  - `\d{3}` - three digits
  - `(?:\.|$)`  - `.` or end of string.

JavaScript demo:

```js
function formatNumber(num) {
  return num.toString().replace(/(?!^)(?=(?:\d{2})*\d{3}(?:\.|$))/g, ',')
}

console.info(formatNumber(2665.68)) 
console.info(formatNumber(102665.68)) 
console.info(formatNumber(111102665.32)) 
console.info(formatNumber(11111111.32))
```

Comment: Just one issue brother, If I am giving negative value like -280.00 its showing -,280.00

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam Then use `/(?<!^-?)(?=(?:\d{2})*\d{3}(?:\.|$))/g`, see  [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/cxOFFD/3)